# Python - Print all items in a string from first instance of item onwards

Tags: python, string, instance

I want to print all items in a sequence starting with the first instance of a particular item. 
To do this I cannot use find or index. I am specifically being asked to use some combination of 'for' statement, linenum(position of an item in the string), length(length of a string) and count(how many times a particular character appears in a string).

So Far I have -

```
def PrintFrom(c,s):
    count = 0
    for item in s:
        if item == c:
           count +=1
    if count > 0:
        print (item)
```

What I'm looking for is this:

```
PrintFrom("x","abcxdef")
->x
->d
->e
->f
```

If anybody could help me out I would be beyond grateful. Thank you.

Comment: [`itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == c, s)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I think your predicate is wrong, should be `x != c`?

Comment: @wilbur Yeah, I derped, thanks!

Comment: This looks fine to me - what does your code currently output when run? Voting to close until you provide what the current output is and how that differs from what you want. Edit - nevermind, just saw the issue. Steven is right.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thank you so much, it runs it perfectly now.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Yeah, thanks anyway - appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it almost exactly right.  Indent your second if-statement to the same level as your first if-statement and your code works. Currently the second if-statement is only encountered after the for-loop has ended, which means it is too late to print the items as they are encountered.

```
def PrintFrom(c,s):
    count = 0
    for item in s:
        if item == c:
           count +=1
        if count > 0: # indented to be inside of for-loop
           print (item)
```

Run with modifications:

```
>>> PrintFrom("x","abcxdef")
x
d
e
f
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with a for loop

```
def PrintFrom(c, s):
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        if ch == c:
            return '\n'.join(list(s[i:]))
print PrintFrom('x', 'abcxdef')
```

Here is how to do it with recursion

```
def PrintFrom(c, s, p = 0):
    if s[p] == c:
        return '\n'.join(list(s[p:]))
    return PrintFrom(c, s, p + 1)
print PrintFrom('x', 'abcxdef')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is only one character length

```
def print_from(start, my_string):
  _print = False
  for ch in my_string:
    if ch == start:
      _print = True
    if _print:
      print(ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

O.Ps code works fine with proper indentation and colons.

```
def PrintFrom(c,s):
    count = 0
    for item in s:
        if item == c:
           count +=1
        if count > 0:
           print (item)

PrintFrom("x","asdxfgh")
```

output:
x
f
g
h

Comment: Correct, but you are a bit late to the game considering two other answers posted six minutes previously also point this out.